# Effective frame limiting

Tags: c++, sleep

I have a simulation that I am trying to convert to "real time". I say "real time" because its okay for performance to dip if needed (slowing down time for the observers/clients too). However, if there is a small number of objects, I want to limit the performance so that it runs at a steady frame rate (~100 FPS in this case).

I tried `sleep()` and `Sleep()` for linux and windows respectively but it doesn't seem to be accurate enough as the FPS *really* dips to a fraction of what I was aiming for. I suppose this scenario is common for games, especially online games but I was not able to find any helpful material on the subject. What is the preferable way of frame limiting? Is there a sleep method that can guarantee that it won't give up more time than what was specified?

Note: I'm running this on 2 different clusters (linux and windows) and all nodes only have built-in video. So I have to implement limiting on both platforms and it shouldn't be video card based (if there is even such a thing). I also need to implement the limiting on just one thread/node because there is already synchronization between nodes and the others would automatically be limited if one thread is properly limited.

Edit: some pseudo code that shows how I implemented the current limiter:

```
while (ProcessControlMessages())
{
    uint64 tStart;
    SimulateFrame();
    uint64 newT =_context.GetTimeMs64();
    if (newT - tStart < DESIRED_FRAME_RATE_DURATION)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(DESIRED_FRAME_RATE_DURATION - (newT - tStart)));
}
```

I was also thinking if I could do the limiting every N frames, where N is a fraction of the desired frame rate. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: What is your measure of acceptable jitter?

Comment: +-20% should be fine. It doesn't have to be very precise, I just don't want the FPS to go over the roof when there are less objects. That normally would've been okay but now I am providing input to another simulation and the results become unpredictable when I am simulating thousands of frames a second. They don't have to be tightly synchronized but should stay wihtin reasonable bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For games a frame limiter is usually inadequate. Instead, the methods that update the game state (in your case `SimulateFrame()`)  are kept frame rate independent. E.g. if you want to move an object, then the actual offset is the object's speed multiplied with the last frame's duration. Similarly, you can do this for all kind of calculations.

This approach has the advantage that the user gets maximum frame rate while maintaining the real-timeness. However, you should watch out that the frame durations don't get too small ( < 1 ms). This could result in inaccurate calculations. In this case a small `sleep` with a fixed duration could help.

This is how games usually handle this problem. You have to check if your simulation is appropriate for this technique, too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having each frame try to sleep for long enough to be a full frame, have them sleep to try to average out.  Keep a global/thread owned time count.  for each frame have a "desired earliest end time," calculated from the previous desired earliest end time, rather than from the current time

```
tGoalEndTime = _context.GetTimeMS64() + DESIRED_FRAME_RATE_DURATION;
while (ProcessControlMessages())
{
    SimulateFrame();
    uint64 end =_context.GetTimeMs64();
    if (end < tGoalEndTime) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(tGoalEndTime - end)));
        tGoalEndTime += DESIRED_FRAME_RATE_DURATION;
    } else {
        tGoalEndTime = end; // we ran over, pretend we didn't and keep going
}
```

Note: this uses your example's `sleep_for` because I wanted to show the minimum number of changes to enact it.  `sleep_until` works better here.

The trick is that any frame that sleeps too long immediately causes the next few frames to rush to catch up.

Note: You cannot get any timing within 2ms (20% jitter on 100fps) on modern consumer OSs.  The quantum for threads on most consumer OSs is around 100ms, so the instant you sleep, you may sleep for multiple quantums before it is your turn.  `sleep_until` **may** use a OS specific technique to have less jitter, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: thank you that's very informative indeed. I think that is acceptable because if a frame finishes really fast (<8ms for 120FPS) then if I suspend one thread for <200ms, I can still compensate for 100 FPS or if its sleeps longer just compensate what I can (still better than what I was doing before!) thanks!